# Jar File stops running after log out

Tags: java, windows, executable-jar

I execute jar file on double click but it stops running as soon as I log out. What I have to do to make it keep going unless I shut down system?

Comment: By log out I presume you Log out of Windows (or some other OS). If so, just lock screen to have the jar running in the background

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that, in your jar file it is written that on logout system.exit(0) or any other logic will be called.